# MongoDb aggregation - query and query again. 2 aggregation stages

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following collection. Each having a "User" name, a "Type" (either "beginner" or "advanced"), and a "Score":

```
[
    {"User": "A",
      Type: "beginner"
      "Score":"Some_X_Value"
    },
    {"User": "B",
      Type: "beginner"
      "Score":"Some_Y_Value"
    },
    {"User": "C",
      Type: "beginner"
      "Score":"Some_Y_Value"
    },
    {"User": "D",
      Type: "advanced"
      "Score":"Some_X_Value"
    },
    {"User": "E",
      Type: "advanced"
      "Score":"Some_Z_Value"
    }
]
```

I want to find **all records** that their 'Score' equal to the value of **'Score' of the Type 'beginner'.**

*The needed 'Score' is unknown!** so cant use simple find query.

So its need 2 query steps:

1. get the needed 'Score' value of the **'Type' beginner only!**.
2. get **all records** that **in** the above 'Score' query results.

The wanted result for example is all records expect the last one:

```
[
    {"User": "A",
      Type: "beginner"
      "Score":"Some_X_Value"
    },
    {"User": "B",
      Type: "beginner"
      "Score":"Some_Y_Value"
    },
    {"User": "C",
      Type: "beginner"
      "Score":"Some_X_Value"
    },
    {"User": "D",
      Type: "advanced"
      "Score":"Some_X_Value"
    }
]
```

How can I do it??

Comment: This can be done by executing a simple `find` query. https://mongoplayground.net/p/tCFWKzG9VRh

Comment: @TomSlabbaert My friend, thanks for your response, but please read again the Q. 
I need 2 stages, first get the wanted scores, and after it, re query all again all the collection. any help?

Comment: You should edit your question to make it clearer, the words you used to describe what you want contradict the example you put, which suggests a simple query. (as user `D` value equals user `A` and `C` value but is still excluded.)

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JCDW-0FpqXN) what you are looking for?